# Possibility of a table-top General Relativity test

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, estimation

NASA famously confirmed Einstein's GR theory and the existence of gravitomagnetism with Gravitational Probe B. Now, question is weather would be possible to create a table-top experiment to measure a man-made gravitomagnetic field effect coming directly from atomic nuclei by using standard NMR or EPR spectrometer techniques to spin atomic nuclei at very high frequencies.

For example, to overcame a problem with small 1% natural abundance, one can use readily available Carbon 13 isotope ( which costs £600 for 1 gram of 99% pure isotope ) and it has a gyro-magnetic ratio of 10.705 MHz/T, which means that in an NMR spectrometer, at B= 6.0 T, its rotational frequency would be 60 MHz. With 99% pure C-13 isotope effect would be almost 100 times stronger then with natural Carbon.

Question is, would such an experiment be able to measure man-made gravitomagnetic field? Not necessarily with Carbon 13, but anything that's good for the job.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism#Gravitomagnetic_fields_of_astronomical_objects) has the formula. Try calculating the size of the effect in a tabletop setup.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That formula is for a single solid body, not for trillions of atomic nuclei. Plus, I'm not really maths person. Don't want to make a mistake and jump into a wrong conclusion.

Comment: It has been shown that it is possible to polarize proton spin in  a block of frozen hydrogen by passing an electromagnet back and forth across the block. If you combine this with the Cavendish experiment, Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks, I'll check that

Answer (score 2):

This is not a feasible approach. The amount of angular momentum you would get by doing this is tiny.

Suppose you took a $1\mathrm{\ kg}$ solid sphere of pure C-13. And suppose (entirely unrealistically) that you could somehow get every single atom excited together. Since there are about $5 \ 10^{25}$ C-13 atoms in a kilogram and since each one has an angular momentum of $\frac{1}{2} \hbar$ that gives a total angular momentum of $L=2.6 \ 10^{-9} \mathrm{\ kg \ m^2/s}$.

This is a truly miniscule amount of angular momentum. By comparison, that sphere would have a radius of about $r=5.4 \mathrm{\ cm}$ and a moment of inertia of $I=11.5 \mathrm{\ kg \ cm^2}$. So to get the same angular momentum you would only need to spin it at $\omega = L/I = 2.3 \ 10^{-6} \mathrm{\ s^{-1}}$

Comment: That actually doesn't sound so bad. You could contemplate liquid hydrogen for an order of magnitude more angular momentum per unit mass. And $10^{-6}$ seconds is once all around per month, I would think the EötWash experiment controls their motion much better than that.